# mysql 複数のselect文をまとめる

Tags: mysql

以下の２つのselect文を１つにまとめることは可能でしょうか？

select name,img,price from items where id=:request

select item_title from categories where id=:request

詳しい方、ご教示下さい。よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: どのような結果を想定していますか？

Comment: name.a img.a price.a item_title.bのように取得したいです。

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.name, a.img, a.price, b.item_title 
FROM items AS a 
INNER JOIN categories AS b ON a.id = b.id 
WHERE a.id = :request
```